# How to get the values in input fields to edit in sharepoint using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have one datatable with edit and delete button, and when I click the edit button, it shows the popup window with input fields and values to edit. But what I need is one new page with input fields and value to edit. The following code is to show the popup window.

```
`<span><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-2x' onclick='edit(" + value.Id + ")' data-target='#ModalForUpdate' data-toggle='modal'></i></span>`
```

This is the code to edit button in datatable. I am using this code in my JS file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// You can use the get method to send value.

```
function edit(id){
  window.location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/form?id='+id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use session storage for this  in your on click function you pass the id of the item, so you can set that id in session storage and redirect to the edit page like

`function edit(edivalue){
sessionStorage.setItem('editvalue', editvalue);
window.location.href="//Your edit page link";`

And next you can use `sessionStorage.getItem('editvalue')` to get the value in Edit page

Try this